# boost::lexical_cast int to string padding with zeros

Tags: c++, string, boost, lexical-cast

I need to create files with generated names. I use `boost::lexical_cast` to transform integers to `std::string`. Is it a possibility to get string with padding zeros;
I have no `c++11 tools`, just everything that `MSVS 2008` supports.

Example :

```
int i = 10;
std::string str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);

// str = "10"
// expect str = "000010"
```

p.s. don't suggest to use sprintf please.

Comment: If you want to keep a cast-y feel about it, just write a templated function that uses a `std::ostringstream` internally but adds padding (possibly with an argument specifying overall width?)....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why `boost::lexical_cast`? Use `std::stringstream`

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::setw(6) << std::setfill('0') << i;
const std::string str = ss.str();
```

Comment: `setw` and `setfill` declared in  `<iomanip>`. `setfill` is inserted on `output streams` so it is better to use `std:ostringstream`. Form more info [setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) and [setfill](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) with the normal stream [manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) for formatting.